# Spring Batch JUnit test not loading application.properties for JobLauncherTestUtils

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

The problem rears its ugly head when the `JdbcJobInstanceDao` attempts to call the `FIND_JOBS_WITH_KEY` query:

```
SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from %PREFIX%JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ?
```

the `%PREFIX%` token is replaced with the value of `application.properties` key `spring.batch.table-prefix` which defaults to `"BATCH_"`.

The application properties are definitely loading from the files as my small test demonstrates:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test") // to load `application-test.properties`
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
// we don't need a web context as we are playing with only server side classes
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE, classes = {TestDatabaseConfig.class,
        MyBatchProperties.class, SpringBatchTestConfig.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {MyBatchConfig.class}) 
// MyBatchConfig has @EnableBatchProcessing and all job configurations.
public class BatchTest {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        Environment environment = applicationContext.getEnvironment();
        System.out.println(environment.getProperty("spring.batch.table-prefix"));
        // above prints MY_SCEHMA_USER.BATCH_ as expected
    }

    @Test
    public void checkJobRuns() {
        try {
            jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); // <-- fails here with the query returning "table not found" because the prefix was not configured correctly.
        }
    }
}
```

*application-test.properties*:

```
spring.batch.table-prefix=MY_SCHEMA_USER.BATCH_
```

I've been working with custom configuration for job runs for a long time but the `JobLauncherTestUtils` doesn't seem to honour these configuration properties.

> I need the different table prefix as the batch database tables are owned by a different schema to the connected database user. (i.e. `MY_APP_USER` trying to access `MY_SCHEMA_USER.BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE`). unqualified references to tables try (and fail) to resolve the batch tables against `MY_APP_USER` instead of `MY_SCHEMA_USER`.

I've tried to create a `JobRepositoryFactoryBean` bean and annotate it with `@ConfigurationProperties("spring.batch")`. However - along with this not working anyway - I don't see why I should configure these this way rather than with properties.

**How to I get the Batch related beans properly configured with application properties in junit tests using JobLauncherTestUtils?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Fixed

The problem was because i was creating my own `BatchConfigurer` bean inside of the `MyBatchConfig` class.

> The BatchConfigurer registers the properties for configuration with each component of the Batch framework (jobRepository, daos, etc...)

This meant that the properties were not being populated through the `@Component` annotated `DefaultBatchConfigurer` class. As to why I decided to place this piece of code in here even I - the author - Am not sure. I guess i need to not code after minimal sleep.

Thanks for indulging my stupidity!